# Uploading HTML files with image links

Tags: javascript, php, html, uploading

I am trying to write a file uploader that will upload HTML files:

```
  <form action="fileupload_handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="upfile" id="upfile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload html" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Which works fine, but with HTML files that contain link to images such as:

```
<img src="/some_path_on_local_disk/a_logo_image.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

The image links may either be absolute or relative paths on local disk.

From all the HTML and PHP I know, I think that it's impossible to write HTML/PHP code that will find all the image links in the HTML and upload them in some way. Note all images are on local disk.

Am I wrong in assuming that? Is there an elegant javascript solution or an open-source API perhaps?

Comment: You are correct - the problem is that you can upload the html file and the image is not embedded in it. That's why IE made their mhtml thing (if memory serves on that name).

Comment: If path is http url like http://example.com/media/aab.jpg
Than there be possibility to upload images.

Comment: @SumanSingh Yes I agree with external URLs, the PHP can go and fetch them.